# Json is returning 3 objects instead of one in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a REST endpoint that I call to request some data, but it returns the same object three times in my JSON response, rather than only returning distinct results.

This is the response I get:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5555 ",
        "label": "MAIN USER (5555)  "
    },
    {
        "id": "5555 ",
        "label": "MAIN USER (5555)  "
    },
   {
        "id": "5555 ",
        "label": "MAIN USER (5555)  "
    }
]
```

This is the controller that's being used to generate the JSON response:

```
@RestController
public class AutoCompleteController {
    private AutoCompleteService autoCompleteService;
    private EntityManager em;

    public AutoCompleteController(AutoCompleteService autoCompleteService, EntityManager em) {
        this.autoCompleteService = autoCompleteService;
        this.em = em;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "jobs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<AutoComplete> getSalary(@RequestParam(value = "autocomplete") String autocompleteValue) {
      return autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(autocompleteValue);
   }
}
```

In turn, the controller calls `AutoCompleteService`:

```
@Service
public class AutoCompleteService {
    private AutoCompleteRepository autocompleteRepository;

    public AutoCompleteService(AutoCompleteRepository autRepo) {
        this.autocompleteRepository = autRepo;
    }

    public List<AutoComplete> retrieveSalary(String jobClassCd) {
        List<AutoComplete>  salaries = autocompleteRepository.findAllByJobClassCdIsContaining(jobClassCd);
        if (salaries.size() <= 0) {
            throw new AutoCompleteNotFoundException(jobClassCd);
        }
        return salaries;
    }
}
```

Comment: your `autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary` is returning 3 objects, it is not a spring boot problem. Just tweak your method to return a single object

Comment: Looking at your question and the answers so far, it seems to me that you need to clearly define the schema for and conventions around your database, including how duplicates are dealt with.  In general, you should disallow duplicate entries like you show from making it into your database in the first place.  I might think that it's only certain fields that are duplicated taken from records that are really different, but that 'id' field that is the same in each case looks really fishy to me.  Each record in your db should have a unique id.  So maybe this is a db cleanup problem?

Comment: You mention that you are trying to return just one object, but then the query logic barfs because your select returns 3 objects and doesn't know what to do.  Assuming SQL here, a "LIMIT 1" in your query (or the equivalent in your DAO logic) should fix that problem. - but ignoring extra data like that is generally not a good idea.  Again, get your data consistent first, and then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your method autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary return only 1 result, check your database to is if there are multiple lines with the same content based on your filter.
If you always want 1 result, then make your return an Object, not List<>.

Comment: That's because you have 3 identical objects. You might think about making them unique.

Comment: That's because your database has multiple results to the same input "autocompleteValue". Change your filter or use .get(0), which I don't think it's the right thing to do.

Comment: So you need to change your retrieveSalary method to make it return a single value

Comment: First you need to show us your implementation. But I would ask you first to check your database, probably you have inserted multiple lines and haven't noticed that.

Comment: @IvanArantes please check service code, and database looks fine.

Comment: "findAllByJobClassCdIsContaining" why is this 'findAll...' if you want only one? is "jobClassCd" unique in your database?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your request is to de-duplicate the information coming from the auto complete service, within the Java code, then an option would be to convert the information into a Set, and then back to a list. This will return just a single unique result, assuming that the hash code and equals criteria are set properly.

```
import java.util.*;

class AutoComplete {
    // Not using getter / setters just for convenience here
    public String id;
    public String label;

    public AutoComplete(String id, String label) {
        this.id = id;
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof AutoComplete) {
            AutoComplete o = (AutoComplete) other;
            return o.id.equals(this.id) && o.label.equals(this.label);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (this.id + "-" + this.label).hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.id + " -- " + this.label;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<AutoComplete> initialList = new ArrayList<AutoComplete>();
        initialList.add(new AutoComplete("555", "MAIN"));
        initialList.add(new AutoComplete("555", "MAIN"));
        initialList.add(new AutoComplete("555", "MAIN"));

        System.out.println(initialList);

        HashSet<AutoComplete> deduped = new HashSet<AutoComplete>(initialList);

        List<AutoComplete> dedupedList = new ArrayList<AutoComplete>(deduped);

        System.out.println(dedupedList);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @RobTaylor thanks for your answer, BUT ... why are you using hard-code values for `initialList`?

Comment: This is just an example that matches what you have, only highlighting the mechanism

Comment: You can copy and paste this into something like https://repl.it and play around with it